Error: class file for okio.ByteString not found
I am attempting to compile a program using the following command line:
javac -cp .:json-20210307.jar:okhttp-4.11.0.jar:okio-3.5.0.jar:kotlin-stdlib-1.9.0.jar RebootDevice.java

I get the following error:
*RebootDevice.java:2: error: package okio does not exist
import okio.ByteString;
           ^
RebootDevice.java:19: error: cannot find symbol
        ByteString byteString = ByteString.encodeUtf8(payload.toString());
        ^
  symbol:   class ByteString
  location: class RebootDevice**

All the jar files are in my current directory.
Where can I download the okio.ByteString package from?
Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.
(PS-I'm a C/assembly guy. Never programmed in Java.... Got this program from ChatGPT!!)
